# What DBZ fight lasted a whole season?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I've heard that *Dragon Ball Z* once stretched a fight (sometimes they say one punch) over most of a season.

Which season was it? What are the episode titles? How did they do it, were there flashbacks or cut-aways, or constant fighting?

Comment: Well, each season is divided into "Sagas". The Frieza Saga, which starts from about episode 36, had probably the longest non-stop fight lasting about 20 episodes (vs Goku). But the fight itself didn't last the entire season.

Comment: This sort of depends on [what you mean by a season](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/1971/24). In the case of DBZ, [there is a commonly accepted definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragon_Ball_Z_episodes). As @JonLin says, the longest continuous fight is ~20 episodes (9 hours). DBZ seasons are all longer than 20 episodes, though some of the shorter ones are around 25.

Answer (score 32):

The Frieza vs Goku battle lasted from the time Vegeta dies to the explosion of Namek spans in [episode 87](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ultimate_Battle) to 105, the infamous "five minute" battle itself starts at [episode 97](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Namek%27s_Destruction).

The fight between Goku and Cell at the Cell Games [starts at](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku_vs._Cell) 177 to 180 and Gohan's fight with Cell [begins at](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Faith_in_a_Boy) episode 181 and ends at 191.

The final battle with Buu spans from [episode 279](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_for_the_Universe_Begins) to 287. This is the most varied battle out of all of them.

So technically, the battle between Frieza and Goku is the longest and most drawn out battle between two characters.

Answer (score 5):

Frieza vs Goku battle was the long lasting one. In episode 87 to 105, the "5 minutes" battle starts at episode 97.

When Gohan can't sense the power level of Goku. He flies from the turret where Piccolo was kept to find Goku. Frieza spotted him and Gohan started to do some time pass with Frieza by keep fleeing. Then Frieza said that after **2 mins**, the whole planet will burst.

I think so even after that there were many episodes passed till the fight with Goku continues with Frieza.